# Getting an incorrect answer with a mercende prime number generator

Tags: javascript, primes

all! recently i've been trying to build a mercende prime number producer/generator, using the lucas lehmer method of testing. the code works for the first 4 numbers, and then fails for the rest. any suggestions? thanks!

```
var totalPrimes = Math.floor(prompt("What would you like the upper limit of 
                                     our search for primes to be?"));
for (var i = 2; i < totalPrimes; i++) {
    var lucasNum = 4;
    var curNumber = (Math.pow(2, (i+1))-1);
    for (var x = 0; i-1 > x; x++) {
        if (lucasNum / curNumber > 1) {
            lucasNum = (Math.pow(lucasNum, 2)-2);
        } else {
            lucasNum = (Math.pow(lucasNum, 2)-2);
        }
    }
    if (lucasNum % curNumber === 0) {
        console.log("The number " + curNumber + " is prime");
    } else {
        console.log("The number " + curNumber + " is not prime");
    }
}
```

Comment: What code were you trying to implement? I haven't found a Lucas Lehmer algorithm that mirrors that one.

Comment: i was trying to make my own code, as a starting problem to try out. thanks!

Comment: First create a verified working algorithm. This is not a mathematics site.

Answer (score 0):

The mantissa (or significand) of a Javascript number is 53-bit wide. Therefore, the biggest integer that can be stored in full precision is:

```
2^53 - 1 = 9007199254740991 = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
```

(You may want to read [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) for more details.)

Your algorithm is likely to hit this limit very quickly. The precision explosion occurs within this statement:

```
lucasNum = (Math.pow(lucasNum, 2)-2);
```

which is included in a loop.

Comment: Thank you! very helpful!